# Windows 10 via Bootcamp: "Setup was unable to use the existing system partition..."

Tags: bootcamp, windows

I'm running macOS Sierra on an early 2015 MacBook Pro with a 500 GB SSD.

I've been trying to get Windows 10 installed via Bootcamp by following this guide: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204990

I've allocated 80GB of space via the Bootcamp Assistant.

I'm getting stuck at the following error:

"Setup was unable to use the existing system partition because it does not contain the required free space"

I *can* go larger, but am not confident that would resolve the issue (I've done some searching and others report an issue with 100GB) and I didn't really want to give Windows that much space.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the error is misleading. I was able to resolve the issue and successfully complete installation by clearing space on the "EFI Partition" by following this guide: [Unable to install Windows 8.1 using Bootcamp, system volume doesn't contain required free space?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/201944/unable-to-install-windows-8-1-using-bootcamp-system-volume-doesnt-contain-requ)