# how to dual boot windows

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, high-sierra, windows, partition

i have MacBook Pro 2012 with High Sierra, i tried the normal way and ran into this problem where it [errors with](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8320198), "Your bootable USB drive could not be created. There is not enough space available on the disc."

So I format it as exFAT as per [this](https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-11201) thread.

What I don't understand here is he said to make a fat 32 partition at step 4, but Windows can't install on a fat32 partition? So i boot my USB using OPTION at startup and it says Windows can't install because it can't install on the partition.

So I format it over there at the Windows and i ran into [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/296947/windows-10-via-bootcamp-setup-was-unable-to-use-the-existing-system-partition) where "Setup was unable to use the existing system partition because it does not contain the required free space." And it advises me to free up space on the EFI partition.

So i do [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/201944/unable-to-install-windows-8-1-using-bootcamp-system-volume-doesnt-contain-requ) to free up space on the EFI partition, but it only frees up my EFI to 11 mb, is there anything else i could do for this or is there anything else I could do to dual boot Windows on my Mac?

Comment: I did some readability edits on your post. I hope I got it all right. One thing though Windows **can read and create** a FAT32 partition but exFAT is needed because some of the Windows installer files are bigger than the file size limit of FAT32.

Comment: yeah but it said NTFS is the only thing i can install a windows on

Comment: i guess if it only for transferring data it can but i don't think you can install windows on FAT32

Comment: Windows installs **on** NTFS, **from** an ExFAT USB stick.

Comment: Yes, like @Tetsujin succinctly said FAT, Fat32, exFAT and NTFS are all file systems invented by Microsoft. But modern versions of Windows can only be *installed on NTFS.* But Windows retains the ability to create, read and write to all of the aforementioned filesystems. See you can drive your Honda Civic and a Cement truck on the public roads but only the cement truck is going to hold 5 tons of liquid cement.

Comment: well thank you for getting in on this, i DID know that windows CAN READ FAT what confused me was at step 4 in this (https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-11201) it said to make a partition of FAT32 to INSTALL  the windows on it, so the problem now is what to do with the EFI that i got or is there any other alternatives to dual boot windows on my mac